# I can't add a new user in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a new user with root privileges from `visudo` in order to log on the Ubuntu system.

When I run Ubuntu a dialog box appears with the name of a user, let's call it "Sr. X". If I click on "Sr. X" the system ask me for the password, which I don't know.
So I'm trying to add a new user with root privileges by running an Ubuntu image from a USB device. After locating the unit in which Ubuntu is installed, I mount it and type `chroot` to turn the path of the Ubuntu image into the root directory.

So far so good, the problem comes when I try to add a new user by modifying `sudoers` file using `visudo`.
User "Sr. X" doesn't appear - why is that? The only thing that appears is

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then, I add my user:

```
Myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

save the changes and reboot the system. When I run Ubuntu, the same dialog box appears, only showing "Sr. X" again. I click on "login as another user", I put "myuser" into the dialog box and the system ask me for a password. What password should I write? I didn't add any password in the sudoers file. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visudo` doesn't add users. Try `useradd`, `adduser`, or (if you know what you are doing) `vipw`.

However, if all you are trying to do is log in, just reset Sr. X's password as root:

```
# passwd userX
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```